# C# publish with visual studio dependance of dependance

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, publishing

My project1 references project2. In project2 I added some dll as link. However when I publish the project, the dll are not in the resulting folder.

Is it possible to do this or I am doom to add the dll directly to the project1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependencies are not copied transitively - I believe you'll have to manually add the reference to project1. You *could* have a postbuild step to copy all the dlls yourself instead, of course.

Comment: I don't know, to be honest - what sort of "publish" are you talking about? ClickOnce? ASP.NET? It's probably easier to just add the reference...

Comment: Right, I was not very clear, I meant a clickOnce. In fact projet2 (and 3) references all required assemblies for some RealTime aspect (and DB dll for project3). It's cleaner if I do not add the reference in project1.

Comment: It may well be cleaner in theory, but I suspect you'll find that it's simpler from a deployment point of view just to bite the bullet and add the references.

Comment: Yep, ok, I finally added the references.